# Null check operator used on a null value error when fetching JSON

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart

I do not get this.

```
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data != null && widget.stored!.b) {
      return new GridView.count(
          children: List.generate(snapshot.data!.length, (index) {
            return _buildCell(snapshot.data![index]);
          }));
    }
  });
```

So, to recap:

```
if (snapshot.data != null && widget.stored!.b)
```

This snippet is where the error seems to be. I am trying to get 'b' and show only those posts (when true).

And I have this in my Stored.dart:

```
class Stored extends Base {
  late bool b;
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to check if the string = "1" and if so, assign true to it:

```
  Stored(Map<String, dynamic> json) : super(json) {
    post-number = json["posts"];
    bool b = post-number == "1";
}
```

With the JSON response being:

```
{"posts":"1"}';
```

I do not get what I am doing wrong? I am trying to only show the posts that number 1 in it, but when trying to fetch, I am getting the `Null check operator used on a null value` error. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that `widget.stored` is `null`. The `!` tells the compiler that it should not be nullable. So use the conditional property access instead:

```
widget.stored?.b == true
```

Comment: If I do that, I get:  Error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.

Comment: Does `widget.stored?.b == true` do the job? (not sure what the data type of `b` is...)

Comment: Hmm, interestingly that should work, but now my list is empty.         post-number = json["posts"];
        bool b = post-number == "1"; As you can see, I am trying to show b, which is becoming a boolean once featured = 1. What am I doing wrong? Because it says that bool b is a local unused variable, while I reference it like this:   bool? b; See also edited post.

Comment: Remove the hyphen from the variable name. Make it `postNumber`. I don't see any `featured` in your code. And "unused" means that you don't use it *after* having defined like you did... which is true. You assign to a variable `b` and then seem to ignore it... at least in the code you have shared. But you are now asking about several problems. A question on Stack Overflow should be about one problem really. If you cannot make it work, ask a dedicated question on one of the other problems you have.

Comment: Thanks, trincot. I do not understand what you mean that I am not using it? I am trying to check it in the if-statement. Isn't that enough? How exactly should I be using it? Will accept your answer btw. I had asked a similar question here, perhaps you can help there as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69950343/is-there-a-way-to-to-show-snapshot-data-based-on-object-value-in-dart-flutter/69951553#69951553